# A way to set parameters in the LXC parent cgroups

Tags: lxc, cgroups

So I have LXC installed, guest containers configured and all.

The LXC containers each go into their own submodule (in cgroup parlance) and each are configured with `cpu.shares` and also the memory they're allowed to use individually and collectively. E.g. something like:

```
lxc.cgroup.memory.limit_in_bytes = 8192M
lxc.cgroup.memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = 4096M
lxc.cgroup.cpu.shares = 100000
```

How would I configure the **parent** cgroup named `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/lxc` by setting the `cpu.shares` inside of it **automatically during system start**; not too early, to have the `lxc` submodule available, and not too late, i.e. after the containers (auto-)started.